# Getting the pressure of a system by series expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-chemistry

> An average number, $N$, of bosons of spin $S = 0$ is conned to a two-dimensional domain
>   with surface $A$. The gas is ultrarelativistic with a single particle energy $\epsilon = cp$, where $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum and $p$ is the absolute value of the momentum. **Compute the pressure, P, of this system as a function of z, A and T.** While still being
>   in the high-temperature regime, use the result for $N(z, A, T)$ to find $P(N, A, T)$ (keep up to quadratic terms in N). Discuss your results and the relation
>   to the ideal gas law.

$N(z, A, T)$ in function of $z$ has been previously calculated:

$$N = \frac{2\pi A}{(h \beta c)^2}(z + \frac{z^2}{4})$$

Where:

$$\beta = \frac{1}{K_B T}$$

$$z = e^{\beta \mu}$$

The following equation also holds:

$$\frac{P}{K_B T} = \frac{2\pi }{(h \beta c)^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^3}$$

With this information we should be able to get $P(N,A,T)$ (keeping up to quadratic terms in N), but I am not getting the stated pressure.

The provided solution is:

$$P \approx \frac{NK_BT}{A} (1 - \frac{N(h \beta c)^2}{16 \pi A})$$

Comment: I can see one or two areas where clarification might help people to answer your question. Firstly, the $n=2$ term in your sum is $z^2/8$, not $z^2/4$, so this is *not* consistent with your first equation. Secondly, maybe it would help to define some quantities such as $z$, and explain what system you are considering, and where the first two equations come from. Can you edit your question to explain these points a bit more?

Comment: @LonelyProf I have added more details. If there is more information you think would be helpful, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks. This clarifies what the series in $z$ applies to, and gives some useful background. I'm puzzled by the appearance of $V$ in that equation, though, when it does not feature in the final solution, or in any other equation. Also, do take a moment to review the [policy on homework and related questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) which may apply here.

Comment: @LonelyProf My bad, actually it has to be $A$ because we are dealing with a surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is clearly an exercise, I don't think it's appropriate to give the full solution, but I see no harm in pointing you in the right direction.

You are aiming to convert an expansion in $z$ into an expansion in the number density $\rho=N/A$. These are often called virial expansions. Your first equation can be written
$$
\rho = q\left[z+\frac{z^2}{4}\right] \qquad\text{where}\qquad
q = \frac{2\pi}{(h\beta c)^2} .
$$
I have defined $q$ just to cut down on needless clutter.
The brute force approach to this would be to solve this equation, to give $z$ in terms of $\rho$,
and then substitute this expression into your series formula for $P/K_BT$ as a function of $z$. You can do this; it's a bit fiddly, since it is a quadratic equation in $z$, but it could be done.

For your purposes, a slightly more straightforward approach is to assume that you will get a result of the form
$$
z = c_1 \rho + c_2 \rho^2 + \ldots
$$
where you need to determine the coefficients $c_1$, $c_2$ etc.
Hopefully you can see why there is no need for a $\rho$-independent term $c_0$, when you look at the equation for $\rho$.
Also, it should be obvious that you don't need to consider more terms like $c_3$ etc, if you are only interested in the final result having the first couple of powers of $\rho$.

So you determine the coefficients $c_1$, $c_2$ by substituting that expression for $z$ into the right hand side of the equation for $\rho$,
and equating the coefficients of corresponding powers of $\rho$ on each side.
The term linear in $\rho$ will give the coefficient $c_1$ immediately:
$$
[\rho^1]:\qquad 1 = q \, c_1 .
$$
The quadratic term in $\rho$ will give an equation for $c_2$, which
also involves $c_1$, 
$$
[\rho^2]:\qquad 0 = \text{I'll leave you to work this out.}
$$
Since you just determined $c_1$, this will be easy to solve to get $c_2$.

So now you have $z\approx c_1 \rho + c_2 \rho^2$ and you can insert this expression into the given series expansion for $P/K_BT$,
only keeping the terms in $\rho$ and $\rho^2$.
If you do all this carefully, you will get the answer provided.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is really helpful! I got $z\approx  \rho -1/4 \rho^2$ which led me to the provided answer :) By the way, for the sake of curiosity, this is the complete exercise and the provided answer: https://imgur.com/a/dnILMPR https://imgur.com/a/hrCNdoK https://imgur.com/a/4i5tei1 What I did not know was how to get EQ 26.